# Создал поле ввода Login, Username и password. В js создал class для валидации. Добавил в CSS блок, который будет виден если ошибка, но не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, валидация

```js
var login = document.getElementById('login').value;
var username = document.getElementById('name').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var mistake = document.getElementById('miss');

var reg = document.getElementById('reg');


class Validate{
    constructor(gmail, username, password){
        this.gmail = gmail;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    validateGmail(){
        if(this.gmail.indexOf('@')> -1){
            return(true);
        }
        else{
            mistake.classList.add('visible');
        }
    }
    validateUsername(){
        this.username.maxlength == 20;
        if(this.username.length <= 20){
            return (true);
        }
        else if(this.username.length >= 21){
            mistake.classList.add('visible');
        }
    }
    validatePassword(){
        this.password.maxlength == 16;
        if(this.password.length <= 20){
            return (true);
        }
        else if(this.password.length >= 21){
            mistake.classList.add('visible');
        }
    }
    all(){
        if(Validate == true){
            mistake.classList.remove('visible');
        }
    }
}


reg.onclick = function(){
    const Start = new Validate(login, username, password);
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.block{
    width: 400px;
    height: 520px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 124, 207);
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px black;
}
.image-header{
    background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/noutbuk_stol_ruki_166631_1920x1080.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    height: 120px;
}
.blur{
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.473);
}
.iput-group{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.inp-for{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.inp{
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.inp:focus{
    outline:solid 4px rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.384);
    transition: 0.1s;  
}
.inp:not(:focus){
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.button-group{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.glob-btn{
    border: solid 3px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: wheat;

    margin: 15px;

}
.google{
    color: white;
}
.google:hover{
    color: rgb(255, 42, 42) !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.glob-btn:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(0, 124, 207);
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.glob-btn:not(:hover){
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.link{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.NO{
    width: 80%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 46, 46);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;    
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: none;
}
.visible{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>JavaScript</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

        <div class="bg">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="image-header">
                        <div class="blur">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iput-group">
                        <div class="inp-for">
                            <input type="text" name="log" id="login" class="inp" placeholder="Zoha@mail.com"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-for">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"class="inp" placeholder="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inp-for">
                            <input type="password" name="pass" id="password"class="inp" placeholder="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="NO" id="miss">
                            Mistake!!!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-group">
                        <button class="ok glob-btn" id="reg">
                            Registration
                        </button>
                        <button class="google glob-btn" id="google" glob-btn">
                            Google
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="link"><p>Create</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="Child.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ну и где вызов методов `Validate`? Вижу, что только создали экземпляр

Comment: `if(Validate == true){` - ??

Comment: Я его вызвал при клике на кнопку reg

Comment: if(Validate == true){ - а класс разве нельзя проверить на boolean?